# can not get gorose 2.0 from github

Tags: go, go-modules

My go version is 1.16, local OS is Windows.

I need to use `gorose` package. When I use the command
`go get -u github.com/gohouse/gorose/v2`at goland terminal, it shows

```
go get: github.com/gohouse/gorose/v2@none updating to
    github.com/gohouse/gorose/v2@v2.1.10 requires
    github.com/gohouse/golib@v0.0.0-20200727025018-43fec7d17e79 requires
    github.com/gohouse/e@v0.0.3-rc.0.20200724104652-25ebf8c9c305: invalid pseudo-version: preceding tag (v0.0.3-rc) not found
```

Anyone can give me a method to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: Check your GOPROXY and try to specify it to _"https://proxy.golang.org,direct"_.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `github.com/gohouse/e` has removed the `v0.0.3-rc` tag from their repository, so the pseudo-version based on that tag is no longer valid. (Go modules have a strong expectation that maintainers do not delete tags that have already been published.)

---

One way to work around this problem is to `exclude` the invalid version, which will cause dependencies on it to be ignored within your module. To do that, add this line to your `go.mod` file:

```
exclude github.com/gohouse/e v0.0.3-rc.0.20200724104652-25ebf8c9c305
```

Then when you `go get github.com/gohouse/gorose/v2` it will re-resolve any missing dependencies on package `github.com/gohouse/e` using the current `latest` version of that module.

---

Another way to work around this problem is to obtain a cached copy of `v0.0.3-rc.0.20200724104652-25ebf8c9c305` from a Go module proxy. It appears that that version may be cached by [proxy.golang.org](https://proxy.golang.org), which you can use by setting [`GOPROXY`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#environment-variables) to `proxy.golang.org,direct` (or unsetting it entirely, since that's the default for most distributions of the `go` command) in your environment.

If you have set [`GOPRIVATE` and/or `GONOPROXY`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#environment-variables), you may also need to adjust those variables to ensure that they are not bypassing the proxy for `github.com/gohouse/e`.

---

Finally, the ideal long-term solution is to fix these dependencies upstream, so that the module dependency graph includes only valid versions to begin with. You could:

- file an issue against the `github.com/gohouse/e` module requesting that they restore the deleted tags, or
- send a PR to `github.com/gohouse/golib` to update the requirement in their `go.mod` file to a version that is still valid, then send a PR to `github.com/gohouse/gorose` to update its dependency on `golib` to the version containing the fix.